# Mudar informação dentro do mesmo modal

Tags: html, ajax

Boa tarde,

Estou fazer uma página para um manual de um software. Acontece que há uma parte desta pagina que é um modal que ao abrir tem uma navbar com 5 botões. A minha intenção é que conforme eu carrego em cada botão da navbar, a informação da mesma apareça no presente modal. Eu escolho outro botão e essa informação troca.

Espero que me consigam ajudar...

Obrigada

Comment: Essa informação viria de um banco de dados ou da própria página?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar **Jquery Ajax**, para que quando o usuario clique em um dos botões, o ajax busque o texto em outro lugar e insira em uma div, sem que a pagina precise dar um reload.

Segue um exemplo pratico:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp